# Eigenvalues of "almost" complete bipartite graph ?!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Please note that I'm just looking for a partial answer to this question.

**Definition**
Let $G=U\cup V$ be a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph),  where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint sets of size $p$ and $q$, respectively.  $K_{p,q}$  is bipartite graph where every vertex in $U$ is connected to every vertex in $V$.

**Background**
It is known that the spectrum of the complete bipartite graph $K_{p,p}$ is $(p, -p,0\ldots,0)$ (see Theorem 3.4 in  [this book](http://file.zums.ac.ir/ebook/051-Graphs%20and%20Matrices%20(Universitext)-R.%20B.%20Bapat-1848829809-Springer-2011-175-$59.pdf)).

Let $E'=\{e_1,\ldots,e_l\}\subset K_{p,p}$, where $l\leq \frac{|V(K_{p,p})|}{2} =p$
Let $G'$ be the graph obtain from $K_{p,p}$ in the following way:
-$V(G')=V(K_{p,p})$
-$E(G')=E(K_{p,q})-\{E'\}$
That means  $G'$ is  the graph obtained from $K_{p,p}$ by removing "relatively" small number of edges (since $|E(K_{p,p})|=p^2$).

**Question?**
Is it possible to calculate the spectrum of $G'$ if $E'$  satisfies certain conditions? for example one of the following:
-$E'$ is a perfect matching of $K_{p,p}$
-$|E'|\leq 4$.
Is there any work in this direction?

**Ideas that could help:**
1-If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $G'$ with multiplicity $l$ then $-\lambda$ is also eigenvalue of $G'$ with multiplicity $l$ (since $G'$ is bipartite graph, see Lemma 3.13 and Theorem 3.14 in   [this book](http://file.zums.ac.ir/ebook/051-Graphs%20and%20Matrices%20(Universitext)-R.%20B.%20Bapat-1848829809-Springer-2011-175-$59.pdf)).
2-From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750971/on-the-eigenvalues-of-almost-complete-graph) we know that if $l$ vertices have the same neighbourhood (that is $N(u_1)=N(u_2)=...=N(u_l)$), then $0$ is eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $l-1$.
3-Since  $0$ is eigenvalue of $K_{p,p}$ with very high multiplicity (that is $|V(K_{p,p})|-2$), then I guess that by removing small number of edges from $K_{p,p}$, $0$ will still be  eigenvalue with high multiplicity. 
4-Interlacing theorem could help in commutating the eigenvalues of $G'$.

Any idea will be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E'$ is a perfect matching then there are eigenvalues $\pm(p-1)$,
each with multiplicity $1$, and $\pm 1$, each with multiplicity $p-1$.

To see this, recall that the eigenspaces for $K_{p,p}$ are:

constant functions on the vertices: dimension $1$, eigenvalue $p$;
functions taking $U$ to $c$ and $V$ to $-c$: dimension $1$, eigenvalue $-p$;
functions that sum to $0$ on both $U$ and $V$: dimension $2p-2$, eigenvalue $0$.

(We regard the adjacency matrix as acting on functions $U \cup V \to \bf R$.)

On $G'$, the first two spaces still consist of eigenvectors,
with eigenvalues $p-1$ and $-(p-1)$ respectively.
The last space splits into two eigenspaces,
each of dimension $p-1$: on one, corresponding vertices of $U$ and $V$ 
map to the same number; on the other, the images of corresponding vertices 
sum to zero.  These eigenspaces have eigenvalues $-1$ and $+1$ respectively.  $\Box$

Comment: Thanks!  I edited just to correct a typo: in $K_{p,p}$ the $0$-eigenspace
has dimension $2p-2$, not $p-2$